# How to set Horizontal scroll enabled for SWT Scrolled Composite

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have a CTabItem inside a CTabFolder and i want horizontal and vertical scrolling inside my tab item. Below is my code :

```
composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));

mainTabFolder = new CTabFolder(composite, SWT.BORDER );
GridData mainTabGD = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
mainTabGD.widthHint = 550;
mainTabGD.heightHint = 350;
mainTabFolder.setLayoutData(mainTabGD);

generalTabItem = new CTabItem(mainTabFolder, SWT.NONE);
generalTabItem.setText("General");


ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(mainTabFolder, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL );

generalTabComposite = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
generalTabComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));

// I have created some SWT widgets here

generalTabItem.setControl(sc);  

sc.setContent(generalTabComposite);
sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
sc.setExpandVertical(true);
sc.setMinSize(generalTabComposite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```

Above code gives me a vertical scroll, but i'm not able to achieve horizontal scroll.
Please let me know where am i going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You are telling the `ScrolledComposite` it's minimal size in your last line of code. If the composite's size is larger than this value, it will not show scrollbars.

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer. Please accept it when you have the time.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the `ScrolledComposite` it's minimal size in your last line of code:

```
sc.setMinSize(generalTabComposite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```

If the composite's size is larger than this value, it will not show scrollbars.